# Find the best next key in a dictionary which value fits in a constrain

Tags: python, algorithm, list, dictionary, greedy

I have a dictionary with names:weights of cows.

```
cows = {'Herman': 7, 'Moo Moo': 3, 'Betsy': 9, 'Lola': 2, 'Milkshake': 2, 'Florence': 2, 'Henrietta': 9, 'Maggie': 3, 'Millie': 5, 'Oreo': 6}
```

I have to create a list of lists from this dictionary using a greedy algorithm. Each sub-list has a constrain: the weight limit is 10. That means, I have to select the biggest cow by weight first and find the next cow that fits in the sub-list. For example, the right answer for the problem with this dictionary would be:

```
[ ['Betsy'],
['Henrietta'],
['Herman', 'Moo Moo'],
['Oreo', 'Maggie'],
['Millie', 'Florence', 'Milkshake'],
['Lola']]
```

I'm trying to create a function to find the next best fit for the subtrip. For example, if the first element of the sublist is 'Herman' (weight of 7 tons), I need to find the next key that fits best the value that gets closer to 10, in this case is 'Moo Moo' (weight of 3 tons). So, here is the function I wrote to find the next fit:

```
def findNextFit(adict, val, limit=10):             
       v=list(adict.values())               # list of the dict's values
       k=list(adict.keys())                 # list of the dict's keys
       diff = limit - val                   # value we are looking for

       if diff in v:                        # Perfect fit.
           return k[diff]

       elif diff not in v or diff < 0:      # No fit. 
           return False

       else:               # Difference is positive but not a perfect fit
           vfit = [i for i in v if i < diff]    # list of candidates
           return k[max(vfit)]                  # key with maximum value
```

When I test this function I get an unexpected result:

```
>>> findNextFit(cows, 7, 10)
'Lola'
```

Where I should have get as a result 'Moo Moo'.

Anybody can point me at what I'm doing wrong in this findNextFit function?. I have been working on it the whole day and I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
 if diff in v:                        # Perfect fit.
       return k[diff]
```

diff is not necessarily the index at which the corresponding key for the entry with value diff would be.

You can fix this by using the index* method:

```
if diff in v:
    return k[v.index(diff)]
```

Similarly in your third conditional you'd have to do: `return k[v.index(max(fit))]`

Also your second conditional should not be an or but rather an and.

With all fixes:

```
def findNextFit(adict, val, limit=10):             
     v=list(adict.values())               # list of the dict's values
     k=list(adict.keys())                 # list of the dict's keys
     diff = limit - val                   # value we are looking for

     if diff in v:                        # Perfect fit.
         return k[v.index(diff)]

     elif diff < 0:      # No fit. Don't need to check if diff not in v because earlier if wouldve caught this case
         return False

     else:               # Difference is positive but not a perfect fit
         vfit = [i for i in v if i < diff]      # list of candidates
         if not vfit: return False
         return k[v.index(max(vfit))]                  # key with maximum value
```

Comment: Actually there is a guarantee for corresponding ordering with `keys` and `values` as long as there's no changes made in between the calls, from [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects): "If keys, values and items views are iterated over with no intervening modifications to the dictionary, the order of items will directly correspond. This allows the creation of (value, key) pairs using zip(): pairs = zip(d.values(), d.keys())."

Comment: @niemmi Dope. I was unsure and didn't have time to check the docs. Thanks for letting me know (y)

Comment: Hi Gowrath. Your code works when adding the following statements inside the else clause after the vfit statement and before the return statement: if not vfit: return False. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a perfect fit, you must take the element in `k` at the index position of that values in `v`, thus you are missing an index lookup:

```
   if diff in v:                        # Perfect fit.
       return k[v.index(diff)]
```

Further issues you're going to encounter are linked to your next test that will always be `True` if the first test was false. Your `else` clause is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to invert the cows:

```
cows = {'Herman': 7, 'Moo Moo': 3, 'Betsy': 9, 'Lola': 2, 'Milkshake': 2, 'Florence': 2, 'Henrietta': 9, 'Maggie': 3, 'Millie': 5, 'Oreo': 6}
```

As

```
{2: ['Lola', 'Milkshake', 'Florence'], 3: ['Moo Moo', 'Maggie'], 5: ['Millie'], 6: ['Oreo'], 7: ['Herman'], 9: ['Betsy', 'Henrietta']}
```

Then you can write you function as:

```
cows = {'Herman': 7, 'Moo Moo': 3, 'Betsy': 9, 'Lola': 2, 'Milkshake': 2, 'Florence': 2, 'Henrietta': 9, 'Maggie': 3, 'Millie': 5, 'Oreo': 6}

def invert(d):
    i={}
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        i.setdefault(v,[]).append(k)
    return i

inverted_cows = invert(cows)
# inverted_cows is a dictionary that has weights as keys and lists of cows as values

def findNextFit(adict, val, limit=10):
       diff = limit - val                   # value we are looking for

       if diff in adict:                        # Perfect fit.
           return adict[diff][0]

       elif diff <= 0:      # No fit. 
           return False

       else:               # Difference is positive but not a perfect fit
           vfit = [i for i in adict if i < diff]    # list of candidates
           if not vfit:
               return False
           return adict[max(vfit)][0]                  # key with maximum value

print findNextFit(inverted_cows, 7, 10)
```

This prints `Moo Moo`. As we were greedy and took the first of the two cows with the same weight.

Comment: Second conditional should be an and (y)

Comment: @gowrath An `and` simply won't do.

Comment: Hi Dan. I'm using Python 3.5 and it does not have the iteritems() method. It works fine with the items() method thought. Also, I have tried the function findNextFit(inverted_cows, 7, 10) and returns the correct value, which is 'Moo Moo', but when I try the following values findNextFit(inverted_cows, 9, 10), I get a ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence.

Comment: Now, after adding the statement "if not vfit" inside the else clause it works like butter. Thank you so much Dan.